# Not able to connect PHP application to db2 database on remote server

Tags: php, docker, db2

Been struggling connecting a PHP site to a remote DB2 database for the last three days in [a docker-compose project I'm working on](https://github.com/bohsen/nginx-db2). I keep getting `Connection failed`:

```
Error: 58031
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1031N The database directory cannot be found on the indicated file system. SQLSTATE=58031 SQLCODE=-1031
```

Here's my docker-compose setup:

```
# /docker-compose.yml
---
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    container_name: nginx
    depends_on:
      - db2
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
      - ./app:/app
    links:
      - php
      - db2
  php:
    container_name: php
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: PHP.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    links:
      - db2
  db2:
    container_name: db2.rn.dk
    image: ibmcom/db2:latest
    hostname: db2.rn.dk
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - "50000:50000"
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=testdb
      - DB_USER=db2inst1
      - DB_PASSWORD=ChangeMe!
      - LICENSE=accept
      ## Creates the database DB_NAME, if its not exists
      - STARTUP_MODE=createIfNotExists
      - DB_CREATE_SCRIPT=create_wdemo.sql
      ## loads an old backup of DB_NAME, 
      ## if the dabase DB_NAME does not exist
      # - STARTUP_MODE=restoreIfNotExists
      # - DB_BACKUP=wdemo.tar.gz
    volumes:
      - './data/db2:/database'
```

And the PHP.dockerfile:

```
FROM php:fpm

RUN apt-get update -qq > /dev/null && \
    apt-get install unzip
RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Documentation
# https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=dsd-installing-data-server-driver-odbc-cli-software-linux-unix-operating-systems
# https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=environment-configuring
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066985/php-connection-to-db2
# https://github.com/nagstaku/php_db2
# https://github.com/php/pecl-database-ibm_db2
# https://github.com/php/pecl-database-pdo_ibm

# Install DB2 php-extensions

RUN mkdir -p /opt/ibm/ && curl https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/linuxx64_odbc_cli.tar.gz | tar -xz -C /opt/ibm/
# if you prefer to keep the file locally, download it and use:

## set env vars needed for PECL install
ENV IBM_DB_HOME=/opt/ibm/clidriver
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ibm/clidriver/lib
# ENV IBM_DB_HOME=/opt/ibm/dsdriver
# ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=IBM_DB_HOME/lib

## install ibm_db2 drivers
RUN pecl install ibm_db2 pdo_ibm
RUN echo "extension=ibm_db2.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ibm_db2.ini
RUN echo "extension=ibm_db2.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN echo "extension=pdo.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN echo "extension=pdo_ibm.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

# 
# RUN echo "ibm_db2.instance_name=db2inst1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

index.php

```
<?php
...
$database = 'testdb';
$user = 'db2inst1';
$password = 'ChangeMe!';
$hostname = 'db2.rn.dk';
$port = 50000;

$conn_string =
    "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=$database;" .
    "HOSTNAME=$hostname;PORT=$port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=$user;PWD=$password;";
$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', '');
if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection succeeded.\n";
    db2_close($conn);
} else {
    echo "<p><b>Using ibm_db2 extension:</b></p>";
    echo "<p><u>Connection failed:</u></p>";
    echo "<p>Error: ".db2_conn_error()."<br />";
    echo db2_conn_errormsg()."</p>";
}
?>
```

Is there something I'm missing regarding the setup, that isn't documented anywhere?

Best regards,
Thomas

Comment: Please edit your question to show your connection-string in the php code. Please verify why you chose to have both the DS driver __and__ the clidriver, as only one of these is necessary, and only one should be installed (but this is not the cause of the immediate symptom).

Comment: PHP-file added.
dsdriver and clidriver was added along the way as none of them worked. Not even sure which one is the correct one regarding using it with PHP.

Comment: The immediate symptom seems to be caused by hostname host.docker.internal not resolving to the db2 container. Fix that first.    As regards the driver, there is no concept of what is "correct", but rather the idea is "use the driver that is __needed__" depending on which functionality you need. In your case, it appears that only the clidriver is needed. The DSDriver includes cli but has extra capabilities specifically allowing you to access the database from the shell with the clp and script easily with SQL in the shell. But you only need php, so you only need clidriver.

Comment: Thx for the pointers.
I've been using [this github project](https://github.com/nagstaku/php_db2) as ressource for my setup. But it's two years old and maybe not up-to-date any longer.
I'll try some adjustments to the db2 hostname.

Comment: Hi @mao. I've tried running some tests with different network settings (using `hostname` - updated docker-compose in thread). Using `docker-compose exec web ping db2.rn.dk` all packets are received. So it seems db2 resolves from web container. But I still get the same error.

Comment: verify that the underlying host (that runs docker) has its software router configured to open the specified db2 port for inbound and outbound tcp traffic. Verify that you can connect to the database (by shelling into the db2 container, becoming the db2instance owner, dotting in the correct db2profile file, and running `db2 connect to testdb` (or whatever you db name is).

Comment: Hi @mao. No problems connecting using `db2 connect...`. Verified using netstat that Db2 is listening on the port I expected it to. But then I thought. Let's start from scratch and I cleared the data volume. And TADA... `Connection succeeded`. If you'd like the points for my question, I'll gladly accept your answer as gratitude for your help.